# State True or false? Does it have at least one zero in the interval?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

The statement is as follows:

If

$\frac{a_{0}}{5}+\frac{a_{1}}{4}+\frac{a_{2}}{3}+\frac{a_{3}}{2}+a_{4}=0$

with $a_{4}\neq0$, then the equation

$a_{0}x^{4}+a_{1}x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{3}x+a_{4}=0$

has at least a root in interval $\left[0,1\right]$.

Remark: I tried searching a counterexample but I have not found, I sincerely believe that is true.

Comment: I edited the tags. If there is a compelling reason for you to include real/complex analysis as a tag, please edit the question to include those reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

You can prove 
$$ \int_0^1 a_0 x^4 + a_1 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x + a_4 ~\mathrm{d} x = 0 $$

Comment: Note, it is somehow funny the question assumes $a_4 \neq 0$: in that case the conclusion is not false; rather, it is trivially true.

Comment: Thanks, excellent response.

Answer (score 0):

Use mean value theorem to the polynomial f(x) of degree 5 whose coefficients are ao,a1,a2,a3,a4.